# getline crashing when coming across a newline

Tags: c++, input, ifstream

I am trying to read in some informations from txt file with `\n` endings.
However whenever I come a cross an empty line, I get a seg fault. However I just want the line to get ignored.

code:

```
std::ifstream config_file (config_);
string input_line;

while (std::getline(config_file, input_line))
  {
    if (??check for newline??)
      continue   
  }
```

I tried so far:
changing getline to these parameters:

```
    (config_file, input_line, '\n')
```

and this if statement:

```
if (input_line.at(0) == '\n')
```

However I always get seg faults ^^'.

Comment: getline discards newlines - you will never detect one

Comment: If `getline` returns with a the stream valid (using it in a condition yields `true`), then you have as a matter of fact detected a newline. Otherwise the functions would not have returned, or the stream would have been `false`.

Comment: And if you want to check for empty lines, check if the string is empty.

Comment: @Some If you get an empty string, you have also detected a newline.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes, edited.

Comment: If you really are interested in newlines, you want to use something like std::get, not std::getline.

Answer (score 1):

Use of

```
if (input_line.at(0) == '\n')
```

to check whether is an empty line is wrong sincce `std::getline` reads and discards the delimiter (`'\n'` in your case).

Instead, use

```
if (input_line.empty())
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline` will discard the newline. 
You can check for [`std::string::empty()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty) to detect an empty line.